# Customize SP 2013 share dialog

Tags: 2013, share, dialog

I need to customize the SP 2013 share dialog, which opens from the Quick Control Box.
Specifically, the text 'Enter names, email addresses, or Everyone'

I found the mentioned text in the WSS.RESX file but altering it doesn't seem to do the trick. Not even after an IISRESET.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Thnx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with simple js:

```
SP.UI.UIUtility.setInnerText(parent.document.getElementById("FieldId"), "YourText");
```

Load the JS on the client side on that pop-up page.